# Adding functions from another file and updating parent's state in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I've got App.js which has a state called layers and I want to update the layers state from layers class.

Below is my layers class which doesn't return anything.
What is the best practise to do this in react js?

```
const layers = createReactClass({
     getInitialState() {
            return {
                layers: [],
            }
        },

      addTileLayer: function () {  
        esriPromise([ 'esri/layers/TileLayer']).then(([TileLayer]) => {
                let tileLayer = new TileLayer(
                    {
                        id: 'XX',
                        opacity: '0.55',
                        visible: false
                    });

                this.setState({
                    layers: [...this.state.layers, tileLayer]
                })
            }).catch((err) => console.error(err));
        },
});

export default layers;
```

Please note I've added the app.js below. Right now addTileLayer function resides inside the app.js

```
let createReactClass = require('create-react-class');

const App = createReactClass({

    getInitialState() {
        return {
            status: 'loading',
            extent: {},
            layers: [],
            searchWidget: null,
            map: null,
            view: null,
        }
        this.handleFail = this.handleFail.bind(this);
    },

    componentWillMount(){
        this.addTileLayer();
        this.addFeatureLayer();
    },

    addTileLayer: function () {
        esriPromise([ 'esri/layers/TileLayer']).then(([TileLayer]) => {
            let tileLayer = new TileLayer(
                {
                    id: 'xxx',
                    opacity: '0.55',
                    visible: false
                });

            this.setState({
                layers: [...this.state.layers, tileLayer]
            })
        }).catch((err) => console.error(err));
    },

       render(){

        const maxZoom = 15;
        const minZoom = 4;
        return(
            <div id = 'container'>
                <div id="searchWidget"></div>
                <div id = 'main-content'>
                    <Map
                        class = 'full-screen-map'
                        mapProperties = {
                            {
                                basemap: 'dark-gray',
                                showLabels : true,
                                logo: false,
                                sliderPosition: 'bottom-left',
                                layers: this.state.layers,
                            }
                        }
                        viewProperties = {
                            {
                                extent: this.state.extent,
                                zoom: 12,
                                minZoom: minZoom,
                                maxZoom: maxZoom,
                                ui: {
                                    components: [this.state.searchWidget, 'compass']
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        onFail={this.handleFail}
                        onLoad={this.handleMapLoad}
                    >
                    </Map>
                </div>
         </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: What is the component hierarchy?

Comment: createReactClass is deprecated. You should use ES6 class.

Answer (score 0):

I think a clean way to do this is to maybe have a callback function passed into layers.addTileLayer

```
layers.addTileLayer((layer) => this.setState({layer:layer}))
```

and your new layers class could be

```
const layers = createReactClass({
      addTileLayer: function (updateLayers) {
        esriPromise([ 'esri/layers/TileLayer']).then(([TileLayer]) => {
                let tileLayer = new TileLayer(
                    {
                        id: 'XX',
                        opacity: '0.55',
                        visible: false
                    });
                updateLayers(tileLayer) //this is new
            }).catch((err) => console.error(err));
        },
});

export default layers;
```

this way you don't need to keep track of the state in two places! and still get to encapsulate this functionality in another class :)

Comment: Hi @ngood97 I've added app.js which has addTileLayer in it! I don't want to render anything from layer.js

Comment: Ohh ok gotcha, so you could do something similar except pass in the callback function as a parameter of addTileLayer in the layers class - tell me if this edit is what you mean

Comment: yes, my app class is getting messy. So I need to extract addTileLayer functionality into another class (layers.js). But the problem is addTileLayer is using layers state from app.js

Comment: It might be a little better though to have the functionality inside the layer class in app.js unless you are thinking about expanding it later

Comment: Oh ok hold on I think i have something for you then

Comment: Thanks @ngood97 but how does this update my state of “layers” in app.js?

Comment: @Newbie you would pass in the function that updates layers in app for example you could pass in (layers) => this.setstate(layers: layers) as the callback and then it would update your app's store